# pylint default filepath in ALE

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, plugin-ale, plugin

I am trying to set up my `pylintrc` file in vim, but am having some difficulty getting it to read from the correct path. It seems to work when I have the file in the directory that contains the vim file I am editing, but if I put it into my vim directory, which is:

```
~/.vim/.pylintrc
```

It doesn't recognize it. How do I tell `vim` to read the `pylintrc` file from that directory? The only settings I have related to it are:

```
Plug 'dense-analysis/ale'
let b:ale_linters = ['pylint', 'mypy']
```

Note: my settings currently work (when the file is in the main directory). However, I am wondering how I can change from where it reads the settings/path.

[Cross-posted from SO (no answers)]

Comment: Places where the file is searched: http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/run.html you can change with `--rcfile`. Not really about vim, unless you need to add the option specially to ale

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks for that. Yes, how could I add that to `ale`, as I think that's what invokes it with the `let b:ale_linters` line.

Comment: https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/06f57ca9733aab6e6b67015917fdfd4bf1c70c48/doc/ale-python.txt#L594

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing from [`:help ale-python-pylint`](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/06f57ca9733aab6e6b67015917fdfd4bf1c70c48/doc/ale-python.txt#L594) that we want to adjust `g:ale_python_pylint_options` to [include `--rcfile`](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/run.html), I would drop

```
let g:ale_python_pylint_options = '--rcfile '.<filename>
```

in wherever the right place is for you. That could be wherever you configure ALE, if a single setting is right; or, it could be in an ftplugin (use `b:…`) if you need to change the name based on the specific file/project/whatever.

For the specific `~/.vim/.pylintrc`, you should be able to do

```
let g:ale_python_pylint_options = '--rcfile '.expand('~/.vim/.pylintrc')
```

It's possible `expand()` isn't necessary if pylint will properly tilde-expand its arguments, but I haven't tested that (a smoke-test would be to run something like `sh -c 'pylint --rcfile '\''~/.vim/.pylintrc'\'' <other options>'` and see if it picks up your settings; run it in your own shell if single-quotes disable all expansion: `pylint --rcfile '~/.vim/pylintrc' <other options>`).

Comment: ben -- awesome, thank you that works!

Comment: Ben -- have you ever used Jedi before: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/30871/how-to-entirely-disable-jedi-completion ?

Comment: @David542 IIRC I tried it once and scrapped it, a bit too invasive in my opinion. Looks like you're having similar experiences. I can only recommend checking the docs (e.g., `:help jedi`) and the code to see if there are knobs you can pull to disable things. Otherwise you might be able to rip out the necessary code to just support `keywordprg`